# Brightness can't be fixed

Tags: 12.04, graphics, brightness, monitor

I have problem with brightness on Ubuntu 12.04. Whenever I restart or turn up my HP ProBook 4515s laptop, brightness is set on the highest level of brightness. Please help me to solve this problem :)

I don't have a problem with brightness on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Open Terminal and run this command:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

In the grub configuration file, find this line and change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save the configuration file and run this command

```
sudo update-grub
```

and restart your laptop.

Comment: Thank you! But now I have new option:) When I set brightness on minimum, my screen is black.